# StatelessActor disappeared when I upgraded to Visual Studio Enterparise 2015 Update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

Last night I upgraded to Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 2. When I opened an existing Azure Service Fabric project this morning I got lots of errors regarding the disappearance of `StatelessActor`. The documentation states that it should be in `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors`, but it is not as seen in the graphic:

[StatelessActor reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtBIK.png)

Any idea what happened to `StatelessActor`?

Answer (score 3):

The actor API has been simplified in the GA release - there are no separate Stateless and Stateful actor classes, only just Actor.

More information at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/03/31/announcing-service-fabric-ga-on-azure-public-preview-of-standalone-clusters-on-windows-server-and-limited-preview-on-linux/

Answer (score 1):

There is no longer stateful/stateless Actor project templates. For stateful actors, you need to annotate/decorate it like:

```
[StatePersistence(StatePersistence.Persisted)]
internal class MyActor : Actor, IMyActor
{

...

}
```

Stateful actors sits on top of reliable services so you get those benefits of reliability/durability. This simplication of the service fabric API really helps
understand the various programming models.